# My WordPress page dies if I remove the port in the URL (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: wordpress, url, haproxy, vhosts

I have a problem with my WordPress page in which, as it appears in the title, if I remove the port from the URL, my page dies. To explain better, it is something like this:

[www.MyPage.com:8091](http://www.MyPage.com:8091) (the page is still alive)
[www.MyPage.com](http://www.MyPage.com) (page dies)

As such I already checked my Vhost and according to me they are well configured as well as I changed the URL directly in the wordpress control panel and the only thing that does that is also kill the page, I also checked my Haproxy (I am using a load balancer) As I also suspected everything seems to be correct and finally I tried both assigning the desired URL through the wp-config file and doing it through the database and nothing worked...

What I want as such is that I can access my WordPress site without the URL having the port in view, so the URL looks like this:

[www.MyPage.com](http://www.MyPage.com) instead of [www.MyPage.com:8091](http://www.MyPage.com:8091)

I'm going to leave part of the Vhost and Haproxy configuration files that I think may be relevant...

VHOST:

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
        ServerName pepitocorps.com
        ServerAlias www.pepitocorps.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress2
        <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress2>
                Options +FollowSymlinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/wp-error_log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/wp-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

HAproxy (partial):

```
frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
   default_backend wordpress

frontend https
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/pepitocorps.com.pem

  acl wordpress_site hdr(host) -i www.pepitocorps.com
  use_backend wordpress if wordpress_site

  acl proxy hdr(host) -i ww2.pepitocorps.com
  use_backend proxy_html if proxy

  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  http-request add-header SSL on if { ssl_fc }

  default_backend wordpress

backend wordpress
   balance roundrobin
   server server1 localhost:8091 check

backend proxy_html
   server server2 localhost:8090 check


frontend stats
  mode http
  bind *:8505
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  stats refresh 10
```

As such I no longer know what to do, I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hand :/

Comment: A load balancer is usually used to divide traffic between multiple servers.  I don't see what the advantage would be to dividing traffic between multiple ports on the same server. All the load is still on one server.  Just run Apache on ports 80 and 443 in this case and remove haproxy.

Comment: I know, but in my case I am learning with this, another thing is that I think I did not explain my problem well, what I want to happen is for the page as such to respond through port 80 and port 8091 (and other ports... .) use them as balancers in the pool.